# Immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered - C# Mongo Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

When trying to update an object in a collection,i get the following error

```
  public void Update(File bookIn) =>
    _files.ReplaceOne(book => book.sha1 == bookIn.sha1, bookIn);
```

**"A write operation resulted in an error.\n  After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: """**

To overcome this issue, i added the following directive,but it does not seem to work

```
[BsonId]
[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
```

Comment: when doing replacements, the value of the _id field of the document in the db and the c# object must match. you have 2 options. either retrieve and set the Id of bookIn before doing the replacement. or match by Id instead of sha1.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ okay.... thanks